# How do I replace the xml element from a nclob type column in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle database locally. One of my table contain one column of type nclob which contains a xml like following:

```
<a>
<b></b>
 ...
 <y>
  <z></z>
  <z></z>
  <z></z>
 </y>
</a>
```

I am trying to write a stored procedure to replace only the tag `<y>` with all its nested children.

I have tried to use updates via XMLELEMENT, updatexml, EXTRACT but none worked

Comment: Please expand your example to show what the expected output you require is, then it will be easier to help you.